# Aplicación CRUD con JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, crud

Estoy trabajando en una pequeña app que valide unos datos contra una BD, ahora bien tengo mi BD en MySQL y la vista realizada en HTML5, CSS  y JavaScript para ciertas validaciones, me estaba preguntando, ¿ es posible que pudiera realizar desde JavaScript una conexión hacia una base de datos sin hacer uso de PHP o un webservice? Sé que JavaScript se ejecuta del lado del cliente, pero con PHP se puede realizar validaciones pero con otro lenguaje por ejemplo Java es posible?

Comment: Buenas, es posible conectar con una base de datos con java, javascript... y cualquier lenguaje. Mi recomendación tras leer tu pregunta es que te mires bien los conceptos de cliente / servidor y arquitectura de software. Porque te darás cuenta que un lenguaje de programación es eso, un lenguaje para programar y el mismo lenguaje se puede usar en el cliente o en el servidor. Espero ser de ayuda, saludos!!

Comment: La pregunta no está del todo clara y podría ser demasiado amplia. Favor de revisar [ask] y acotar tu pregunta a a Java o JavaScript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es posible pero nunca lo hagas del lado del cliente por cuestiones de seguridad.

El servidor de tu base de datos no tiene que tener acceso nunca a internet, siempre tienes que explotarla desde un intermediario en otro servidor ya sea con PHP, JAVA, C#, etc y la cadena de conexión, pasword y usuario en archivos de configuración que no sean visibles en internet.

Si estas mas acostumbrado a usar javascript puedes instalar Node.js en tu servidor y es practicamente un javascript del lado del server.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por el comentario amigo, la cuestion es lo contrario estoy mas acostumbrado a usar java web con jsf usando frameworks como primefaces para desarrollar mis apps, pero cuestiones como validar hacia una bd es decir mando a un .js los parametros usuario y contraseña, pero como se mandaria esos parametros a un servlet o bean de java? Para posteriormente mandarlo a mi servicio que se encargaria de realizar la consulta a la bd, Esas es mi duda, cumplir con el Modelo vista controlador...pero las cosas como validar que un formulario esta completo quede del lado del cliente

Comment: aquí te explican como validar un formulario, espero te sirva https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Comment: gracias por el comentario amigo, esas validaciones como textfields que faltan por rellenar estan listas, lo que quiero saber es validar un usuario y una contraseña almacenadas en una base de datos, desde el javascript hacia un servicio en una clase java que conecta a una bd

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando una capa front como un mini sitio (solo Html, Js, css, JQuery, Ajax, Angular..), una opción es Angular en estos momentos estoy haciendo algo parecido , creando un WS REST en java el cual expone los datos que consulte el usuario, al estar expuesto mediante el angular se crean los controladores, controller, backend , y el facade para capturar la información y darle seguridad a la misma, no sé si sea lo que quieras.

Comment: si amigo algo asi, pero veo que obligatoriamente se debe crear el webservice para comunica el backend con el front

Answer (score 0):

De seguro y por seguridad necesitas ejecutar las funciones de tu CRUD en el servidor, ya sea con PHP, JAVA o si prefieres javascript mírate de instalar Node en tu servidor.